# Why my PHP code cannot exec r script. when i tried to run it from PHP exec function

Tags: php, r, database, exec

My R Script :

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='root', dbname='skripsi',host='127.0.0.1')
user=dbReadTable(mydb,"users")
user[1,]$id=10  
user[1,]$name="gelaaa"
user[1,]$email="Gelaaang@rocketmail.com"
newuser=user[1,]
dbSendQuery(mydb, "SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;")
dbWriteTable(mydb,"users",newuser,append = TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

My PHP Code :

```
public function forecastCal()
    {
        $output = exec("D:\R-4.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe  D:\applications\coba-laravel\public\js\cicip.R");
        dd('berhasil');
        return $output;
    }
```

i tried to change database data from my R script. when im using R GUI the script get executed well. but when i tried exec at php. my code did not run. how i can run R script at My PHP code?

Comment: What does the R code do? If just mysql interaction why not do that in PHP? Do you expect `$output` to have a value in it?

Comment: i actually use that script jusr for testing is the exec function running at my program. the actual script is want to change data at database using prediction on R forecasting. but right now it seems that exec function didnot running @user3783243

Comment: when i type fucntion didnot running i mean the `exec` didnot return anything or change anything

Comment: You'd want ` exec("D:\R-4.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe  D:\applications\coba-laravel\public\js\cicip.R", $output);` then `print_r($output)` to see what it had/has. Additionally does PHP run as the same user you ran the R with?

Comment: i just want `exec("D:\R-4.1.0\bin\Rscript.exe D:\applications\coba-laravel\public\js\cicip.R");` running and append mydatabase. the $output is not necessary.  @user3783243

Comment: "does PHP run as the same user you ran the R with?"?